# Странное поведение font-family

Tags: css3, веб-программирование, html, html5, css

Нужно использовать шрифт Nimbus Sans L

в css написал :

```
font-family:Arial,Helvetica,"Nimbus Sans L",sans-serif;
```

но вместо Nimbus Sans L используется sans-serif(получается что шрифт не найден т.е не установлен в системе.хотя на самом деле он есть)

если написать так:

```
font-family:"Nimbus Sans L",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
```

то шрифт подключатся и используется нормально.

ubuntu 13.04 проверял в firefox 26.0 + firebug в других браузерах на ubunte тоже самое.
Этот шрифт стандартный в ubuntu.
Чем может быть вызвано такое странное поведение?

Answer (score 4):

Какой шрифт вы первым укажете, тот и будет использоваться. Если шрифт не будет найден, то будет использоваться тот, который написан после него. То есть в примере ниже у вас никаким макаром не будет использоваться Nimbus Sans L, так как первым указан Arial. А Arial в убунте вроде тоже стандартный

```
font-family:Arial,Helvetica,"Nimbus Sans L",sans-serif;
```

А в этом примере шрифт Nimbus Sans L первый в списке, поэтому браузер будет использовать его.

```
font-family:"Nimbus Sans L",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
```

Comment: Про порядок загрузки шрифтов я знаю.Но в ubuntu нет arial и helvetica зато есть nimbus.И по логике он должен подключиться.но в итоге он не подключается и браузер использует sans-serif.
А если nimbus первый в списке то он успешно подключается.Я вот и не могу понять почему если он первый в списке то все норм,а если нет то он не подключается.

вот что в firebug:
http://5.firepic.org/5/images/2013-12/26/6li8owhea6yf.jpg
http://5.firepic.org/5/images/2013-12/26/2u7bosr7irlr.jpg

Comment: @Dnebl00, есть предположение, что если браузер на убунте не находит первый шрифт, то и остальные не подключаться. Вот на этом скриншоте http://5.firepic.org/5/images/2013-12/26/6li8owhea6yf.jpg все шрифты серого цвета, а здесь http://5.firepic.org/5/images/2013-12/26/2u7bosr7irlr.jpg первый шрифт синий. То есть подключаемый шрифт обязательно должен присутствовать в системе и быть первым в списке.

Но повторюсь, это лишь предположение. Возможно меня поправят гуру убунты.

Comment: сейчас попробовал другой шрифт из стандартных в ubuntu такая же проблема.похоже что это баг или фича ubuntu.интересно как будет в других *nix системах)